# TextViewEx, (Textjustify)

Tags: android, text, textview, text-justify

my problem is this, using TextViewEx (https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android) class texts to justify my android application works fine until the text over a carriage return appear \ n, when this happens the text is cut losing asin several lines of this, I need a solution to justify text without html injection, to change the font size if the application is open from mobile or from a tablet, if know what the problem is and can help me I thank you.

I will put the code in my application:

code xml:

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_border" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_fecha_promociones"
                style="@style/fechaDentroxlarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="24/05/2014" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_titulo_promociones"
                style="@style/tituloDentroxlarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/comparte"
                android:text="Titulo" />

            **<com.xxxxx.tools.TextViewEx
                android:id="@+id/txt_noticia_promociones"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/img_promo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="noticia"
                android:textColor="@color/txtBlanco" />**

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/comparte"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_fecha_promociones"
                android:onClick="compartir"
                android:src="@drawable/share_icon_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_promo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_titulo_promociones"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/promo1" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

code java:

```
public class xxxxx extends NavegacionActivity {

    TextView txt_servicio;
    TextViewEx txt_descripcion;
    TextView prueba;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_servicios_dentro);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);

        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(100);

        txt_servicio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo_servicio);
        txt_descripcion = (TextViewEx) findViewById(R.id.txt_descripcion_servicios);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        txt_servicio.setText(i.getStringExtra("servicio"));
        txt_descripcion.setText(i.getStringExtra("descripcion"),true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(this, xxxx.class);
        startActivity(i);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the classes `TextJustifyUtils.java` and `TextViewEx.java` in the root of your project

In your  XML Replace TextView --->> `com.example.myaplication.TextViewEx`

Comment: Make sure to check the latest version of the library. It has refractored and improved so that it is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to TextViewEx.java and change to this code:

```
@Override
public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics();
    super.setPadding((int) ((left + (metrics.density * 10))), top,
            (int) (right + (metrics.density * 10)),
            (int) (bottom + (metrics.heightPixels * 1.5)));
    Log.i("Log", "metrics : " + metrics);
 }
```